# SharePoint 2013 MyTasks not displaying tasks from all the sites

Tags: sharepoint, task

I have a site (Site A with URL http://abc/project/SiteA). I did a backup and restore to the same farm with a different site (Site B with URL http://abc/project/SiteB). I realized that all the tasks in Site A are reflected in MyTasks. However, all the sites in Site B are not. There shouldn't be any issues with the Work Management Service as some of the tasks are showing up.

Please advise what I should do.

I have to use backup and restore method as it acts as a template for many of the project teams in my company. I have tried save site as template, but there would be too much configurations to be made when creating a new site with it.

Thanks a lot.